# Label in [cell viewWithTag:] is always returned as nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

I'm struggling with this basic thing for more than a day and it drives me crazy! Funny thing is, I have very similar thing on other screen and it works just fine! I have done this a thousand times, but never experienced something so odd. Maybe is this behavior in iOS 8 only?

On my very simple Prototype cell I have two labels with tags 102 and 103. But when I want to set text to them, they are always nil.

I have double checked that identifier is correct and that tag is the same as in Storyboard.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString * identifier = @"secondReusableIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    }

    for (UIView *subview in [cell subviews]) {
        NSLog(@"subview: %lu", subview.tag); // prints 0
    }

    UILabel * label1 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:102]; // returns nil
    UILabel * label2 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:103]; // returns nil
    if (self.items.count) {
        MyObject *obj = [self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        label1.text = obj.someProperty;
        fuelPrice2.text = obj.someOtherProperty;
        }
    }
    return cell;
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Where do you add your label1 & label2?

Comment: In Storyboard inside prototype cell with appropriate tags.

Comment: Since `UITableViewCell` is being reused all the time, you can't rely on the tag. You should make a custom `UITableViewCell` class with `UILabel` property instead.

Comment: but the same thing worked for me for a long time now for different projects, even in the same application, but on different screen? Anyway, I will try that and I will let you know, thanks!

Comment: Although you might have done this a million times, as I have too I assure you, you might have different reuse identifiers in both the storyboard and in the code, so it's worth double checking to ensure that they are indeed both the same. Easy mistake to make.

Comment: For outlets, I would have to create custom class for cell, which I don't want to, since I'm using Prototype cell. You can't create outlet to your ViewController class!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you are creating a new cell, that it's not the same than you have in Storyboard.

Change this: This is the old way, or the way you use when the cell is by code or nib, and you don't use storyboard. This code means.

```
      NSString * identifier = @"secondReusableIdentifier";
// If I have available a cell with this identifier: secondReusableIdentifier, let's go to use it.
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
if (cell == nil){
 // If not, we create a new cell with this identifier. This methods is previous to storyboard, and this methods create a new cell, but does´t look in Storyboard if this identifier exist, or something like that.

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
}
```

To this, in other hand when Apple launched storyboard the framework grow with this methods, that work in this way: If there is a cell free use it, if not it look in Storyboard for a cell with this identifier and create a new cell with this info. (You can use this methods also by code and with nib file, but you must register the class before...).

```
 // Be sure than: "secondReusableIdentifier", it's its identifier in storyboard
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"secondReusableIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: It worked! But how? Can you explain a little more in depth what is the catch here?

Comment: Ok, I´m going to explain a litle bit in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing this:

```
NSString * identifier = @"secondReusableIdentifier";
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
if (cell == nil){
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
}
```

**BY**

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"secondReusableIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

> for creating a cell will solve your problem because, it always returns a cell. It either re uses existing cells or creates a new one and returns if there are no cells.

The most important difference is that the `forIndexPath`: version crashes if you didn't register a class or nib for the identifier. The older (non-forIndexPath:) version returns nil in that case.

You must register a class or nib for using this. But if you create your table view and your cell prototypes in a storyboard, the storyboard loader takes care of registering the cell prototypes that you defined in the storyboard.

Hope this helps.. :)

Answer (score 0):

If

```
for (UIView *subview in [cell subviews]) {
    NSLog(@"subview: %lu", subview.tag); // prints 0
}
```

prints 0, why do you do this??

```
UILabel * label1 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:102];
UILabel * label2 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:103];
```

So, if you created a custom cell with IB, you have to create a custom class and use it instead of a simple `UITableViewCell`

Comment: I am using Prototype cell, so no need for custom classes... It shouldn't print 0, that's the point. As I stated above, same approach works on different UIViewController.